# Python print works differently on different servers

Tags: python, unicode, twisted

When I try to print an unicode string on my dev server it works correctly but production server raises exception.

```
File "/home/user/twistedapp/server.py", line 97, in stringReceived
    print "sent:" + json
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/python/log.py", line 555, in write
    d = (self.buf + data).split('\n')
exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Actually it is twisted application and print forwards to log file.

repr() of strings are the same. Locale set to en_US.UTF-8.

Are there any configs I need to check to make it work the same on the both servers?

Comment: What OSs and Python versions are the servers running?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 Server both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode is not supported by Twisted's built-in log observers.  See http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/989 for progress on adding support for this, or to see what you can do to help out.

Until #989 is resolved and the fix is in a Twisted release your application is deployed on, do not log unicode.  Only log `str`.

Comment: It would be ok if I would need to encode or decode or something. But production server requires to do decode('utf8') and dev server don't allow to do it.

Answer (score 7):

`print`ing of Unicode strings relies on `sys.stdout` (the process's standard output) having a correct `.encoding` attribute that Python can use to encode the unicode string into a byte string to perform the required printing -- and that setting depends on the way the OS is set up, where standard output is directed to, and so forth.

If there's no such attribute, the default coded `ascii` is used, and, as you've seen, it often does not provide the desired results;-).

You can check `getattr(sys.stdout, 'encoding', None)` to see if the encoding is there (if it is, you can just keep your fingers crossed that it's correct... or, maybe, try some heavily platform-specific trick to guess at the correct system encoding to check;-).  If it isn't, in general, there's no reliable or cross-platform way to guess what it could be.  You *could* try `'utf8'`, the universal encoding that works in a lot of cases (surely more than `ascii` does;-), but it's really a spin of the roulette wheel.

For more reliability, your program should have its own configuration file to tell it what output encoding to use (maybe with `'utf8'` just as the default if not otherwise specified).

It's also better, for portability, to perform your own encoding, that is, *not*

```
print someunicode
```

but rather

```
print someunicode.encode(thecodec)
```

and actually, if you'd rather have incomplete output than a crash,

```
print someunicode.encode(thecodec, 'ignore')
```

(which simply skips non-encodable characters), or, usually better,

```
print someunicode.encode(thecodec, 'replace')
```

(which uses question-mark placeholders for non-encodable characters).

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that on UNIX systems, sys.stdout.encoding is set based on the `LANG`, `LC_ALL` and `LC_CTYPE` environment variables, and that it is *only* set if sys.stdout is connected to a terminal. The same working prints can unfortunately break when you redirect output to a file or another program. This makes it even more important to explicitly encode your unicode.

Comment: It doesn't work cause print outputs to logs. I updated my question. Thanks for your response. Locale set to en_US.UTF-8 on the both servers.

Comment: I randomly tried different encodings and mystring.decode('utf8') seems to work on the production server. But it raises exception on the dev:

Comment: @Alex Never experienced this problem, but great answer. I'm sure this info will come in handy in the future :)

Comment: @Gregory, so, on the dev, use `mystring.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)` (definitely **NOT** `.decode` as you say you're doing, that's simply crazy and will work under **no** circumstances -- what are you trying to accomplish that way?!), `'utf8'` on the prod. `getattr(sys.stdout, 'encoding', 'utf8')` will give you the right codec name on either system (and **do** try the `'replace'` for added safety, too!).

Comment: Actually, `unicode.decode()` *will* work if the unicode happens to be encodable in ASCII :-) But as soon as it contains non-ASCII data, *poof*.

Comment: @Thomas, it "works", at best, by doing no operation, i.e., _no_ "work"; so, while you can hope it won't actually blow you away, it still, even in those lucky accidental cases, doesn't _work_ (by any sensible definition of "work";-).